# Regex to match numbers except numbers between quotes

Tags: regex

I'm formating some basic sql statements.

INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Text with 20', 20.65, 70, 80)

Is there any regex to match all numbers except the numbers inside strings?
If you have a regex pattern to avoid digits in comments too, it will be nice!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language / platform are you using, and what have you tried so far? Also, give an example of 'digits in comments' that you don't want to match? e.g. `-- 20`, `// 20`, `# 20`, or `/* 20 */`?

Comment: You need to tag the question with the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks... I will put comments with -- No specific language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a look ahead for an *even* number of following quotes (an even number means the match is *outside* quotes):

```
-?\d+(.\d+)?(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/3XvcLuPRCl) showing matching as follows:

> INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Text with 20', **20.65**, **70**, **80**, 'more text 1234 foo', **9**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
(?=[,(])[^']*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^']*?(?=[,)])
```

This will match only within the `(..)`.
Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/pW7aJ2)
EDIT -
 
The escaped regex for use in c#-

```
(?=[,(])[^']*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)[^']*?(?=[,)])
```

Comment: @Riera check the edit. It seemed to work in regexpal.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your input is limited, this may work for you.

```
(?:\(|, )(\b[\d.]+\b)(?:,|\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WELL7ooO8XpuTQ6f)

Note that you'll need to back the search-location by a character after each match. This places the number into capture group 1, and requires the decimal to be in the middle of the number (not at the ends), although it does not prevent multiple decimals.

Although it correctly does *not* match these quoted numbers:

```
'1000, 2000'
```

it will *incorrectly* capture these:

```
'Some numbers that really should not be matched: (1, 2)'
```

It also doesn't understand when quotes are escaped. But depending on how limited your input is, this may suffice, or at least be a starting point.

Comment: What if there are several quoted values with numbers *between* those? Eg `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Text with 20', 20.65, 70, 80, 'more text 1234 foo', 9)`

Comment: Your input works okay in Debuggex, as far as I can see. Of course, a comma-space-then-number inside the quotes--or, for that matter, an open-paren-then-number--will be incorrectly captured. I'll add qualifiers to my answer.