# Sed and regex to match all number except as part of another pattern

Tags: sed

I need to use sed to match replace number patterns, but only if they aren't part of something else. Example:

Input

```
echo "Execution error for request 40205911. JBO-12345: Reason: Expected meta model version with uuid '34a659f5-ad37-4fea-9593-95a1a818adbb', but retrieved meta model version with uuid '8a3de0d2-fcd9-4bfd-b4a7-070679dc0184'"
```

sed file:

```
s/([0-9a-f]{9}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/########-####-####-####-############/g
s/[0-9]{5,8}/########/g
s/[0-9]/#/g
```

Desired output:

```
Execution error for request ########. JBO-12345: Reason: Expected meta model version with uuid '########-####-####-####-############', but retrieved meta model version with uuid '########-####-####-####-############'
```

But hat I am getting is:

```
Execution error for request ########. JBO-###: Reason: Expected meta model version with uuid '##a###f#-ad##-#fea-####-##a#a###adbb', but retrieved meta model version with uuid '#a#de#d#-fcd#-#bfd-b#a#-########dc####
```

I've some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457805/regex-to-match-numbers-except-numbers-between-quotes) that describe (I think) what I need; a look ahead reference

Comment: The first fragment of the UUID has 8 characters, not 9, yet you have `[0-9a-f]{9}` in your first regex.

Comment: having `s/[0-9]/#/g` as the last line? It is saying  *"If I didn't substitute you before, now replace anything that remains"*. Think about it, that can be your only line of code!, right? (-;?! Can't spend time on the rest of it. Good luck.

Comment: That last line of code would replace the numbers in `JBO-12345` which is not what I want. I recognize it's wrong but wasn't sure how to proceed to get it right

Comment: @InSync - That's a hold over from other samples I have and a detail I missed. These aren't actual compliant UUIDs either - I didn't come up with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ":a;s/( |#)[0-9]|('[^,]*)[[:alnum:]]/\1\2#/;ta;" input_file
Execution error for request ########. JBO-12345: Reason: Expected meta model version with uuid '########-####-####-####-############', but retrieved meta model version with uuid '########-####-####-####-############'
```

Create a label `a` to branch back to if a substitution is successful when the pattern:

`space followed by an integer`

`hash` # `followed by an integer`

`A single quote` ' `up to a comma removing all alphanumeric characters in between`

is found then replace with a `#` hash each time a match is found.

Comment: Well, it works with `gsed` (not the built in one with mac) - So, credit you. But I would love an explanation :)

Comment: You definitely answered the question as asked, but now it has another issue: the number patterns aren't always the same length, but I need them to have the same number of hashes so I can `normalize` them. I am looking for output patterns and stripping out the numbers so I can then `uniqify` them.

Comment: I couldn't edit my last comment, but subsequent substitutions fix this :)

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Added an explanation